# Generating an Attribute Error when appending to a python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, append, attributeerror

I am generating an Attribute Error when appending to a python dict.

I want to build a dictionary where the US states are the keys and college towns are the values. The objective is to read a textfile with that information. My code generates an attribute error in line 23[attribute error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rpQT.gif).

Note: a related question was posted (this is a class assignment), however that question focused on string extraction. This question is about generating a Py-dict with key value pairs after the string extraction and needs help to resolve the attribute error when trying to append "RegionName" (the value).

Desired outcome:
Dict = {Alabama': 'Auburn', ‘Florence', Jacksonville', 'Livingston', 'Montevallo', 'Troy', 'Tuscaloosa', 'Tuskegee', 'Alaska': 'Fairbanks', 'Arizona': 'Flagstaff', 'Tempe', 'Tucson’, etc. }

Code:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

unit = pd.read_table('university_towns.txt', sep='\n', names=['a'], 
header=None)

college =''
states = []
colleges = []
dict = defaultdict(list)

hand = open('university_towns.txt')
for line in hand:
   state = re.findall('(.+)\[edit\]', line)
   if len(state) != 0:
      State = line.split('[')
      State = State[0].rstrip()
      dict[State] = dict.get(State,0)
      states.append(state)

  if len(state) == 0:
     college = line.split('(')
     RegionName = college[0].rstrip()
     dict[State].append(RegionName)
     colleges.append(RegionName)
  dict
```

[text file is based on info from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_college_towns#College_towns_in_the_United_States  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rpQT.gif): https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkEcJ.gif

> ```
> > sample data: Alabama[edit] Auburn (Auburn University)[1] Florence
> > (University of North Alabama) Jacksonville (Jacksonville State
> > University)[2] Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2] Montevallo
> > (University of Montevallo)[2] Troy (Troy University)[2] "Tuscaloosa
> > (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4]"
> > Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5] Alaska[edit] Fairbanks (University
> > of Alaska Fairbanks)[2] Arizona[edit] Flagstaff (Northern Arizona
> > University)[6] Tempe (Arizona State University) Tucson (University of
> > Arizona) Arkansas[edit] "Arkadelphia (Henderson State University,
> > Ouachita Baptist University)[2]" "Conway (Central Baptist College,
> > Hendrix College, University of Central Arkansas)[2]" Fayetteville
> > (University of Arkansas)[7] Jonesboro (Arkansas State University)[8]
> > Magnolia (Southern Arkansas University)[2] Monticello (University of
> > Arkansas at Monticello)[2] Russellville (Arkansas Tech University)[2]
> > Searcy (Harding University)[5] California[edit] Angwin (Pacific Union
> > College)[2] Arcata (Humboldt State University)[5] "Berkeley
> > (University of California, Berkeley)[5]" "Chico (California State
> > University, Chico)[2]" "Claremont (Claremont McKenna College, Pomona
> > College, Harvey Mudd College, Scripps College, Pitzer College, Keck
> > Graduate Institute, Claremont Graduate University)[5]" "Cotati
> > (California State University, Sonoma)[2]" "Davis (University of
> > California, Davis)[1]" "Irvine (University of California, Irvine)"
> > "Isla Vista (University of California, Santa Barbara)[2]" "University
> > Park, Los Angeles (University of Southern California)" "Merced
> > (University of California, Merced)" Orange (Chapman University) Palo
> > Alto (Stanford University) "Pomona (Cal Poly Pomona,
> > WesternU)[9][10][11] and formerly Pomona College" Redlands (University
> > of Redlands) "Riverside (University of California, Riverside,
> > California Baptist University, La Sierra University)" "Sacramento
> > (California State University, Sacramento)" "University District, San
> > Bernardino (California State University, San Bernardino, American
> > Sports University)" "San Diego (University of California, San Diego,
> > San Diego State University)" San Luis Obispo (California Polytechnic
> > State University)[2] "Santa Barbara (Fielding Graduate University,
> > Santa Barbara City College, University of California, Santa Barbara,
> > Westmont College)[2]" "Santa Cruz (University of California, Santa
> > Cruz)[2]" "Turlock (California State University, Stanislaus)"
> > "Westwood, Los Angeles (University of California, Los Angeles)[2]"
> > Whittier (Whittier CollegeRio Hondo College) Colorado[edit] Alamosa
> > (Adams State College)[2] Boulder (University of Colorado at
> > Boulder)[12] Durango (Fort Lewis College)[2] Fort Collins (Colorado
> > State University)[13] Golden (Colorado School of Mines) Grand Junction
> > (Colorado Mesa University) Greeley (University of Northern Colorado)
> > Gunnison (Western State College)[2] "Pueblo, Colorado (Colorado State
> > University-Pueblo)" Connecticut[edit] "Fairfield (Fairfield
> > University, Sacred Heart University)" Middletown (Wesleyan University)
> > New Britain (Central Connecticut State University) "New Haven (Yale
> > University, University of New Haven, Southern Connecticut State
> > University, Albertus Magnus College, Quinnipiac University)[14]" "New
> > London (Connecticut College, US Coast Guard Academy, Mitchell
> > College)[2]" Storrs (University of Connecticut)[2] Willimantic
> > (Eastern Connecticut State University)[2] Delaware[edit] Dover
> > (Delaware State University)[1] Newark (University of Delaware)[1]
> > Florida[edit] Ave Maria (Ave Maria University) Boca Raton (Florida
> > Atlantic University) Coral Gables (University of Miami) DeLand
> > (Stetson University)[5] Estero (Florida Gulf Coast University)
> > "Gainesville (University of Florida, Santa Fe College)" Orlando
> > (University of Central Florida) "Sarasota (New College of Florida,
> > Ringling College of Art and Design, State College of Florida,
> > Manatee-Sarasota, University of South Florida Sarasota-Manatee)" St.
> > Augustine (Flagler College) St. Leo (St. Leo University) "Tallahassee
> > (Florida State University, Florida A&M University)" Tampa (University
> > of South Florida) Georgia[edit] Albany (Albany State University)
> > Athens (University of Georgia)[15] "Atlanta (Georgia State University,
> > Georgia Tech, Emory)[2]" Carrollton (University of West
> > Georgia)[2]*Dahlonega (North Georgia College & State University)[2]
> > Demorest (Piedmont College)[2] Fort Valley (Fort Valley State
> > University)[2] Kennesaw (Kennesaw State University) Milledgeville
> > (Georgia College & State University)[2] Mount Vernon (Brewton-Parker
> > College)[2] Oxford (Oxford College) "Rome (Berry College, Shorter
> > University)" "Savannah (Armstrong Atlantic State University, Savannah
> > State University, Savannah College of Art and Design)" Statesboro
> > (Georgia Southern University)[5] Valdosta (Valdosta State
> > University)[2] Waleska (Reinhardt College)[2] Young Harris (Young
> > Harris College)[2] Hawaii[edit] Manoa (University of Hawaii at
> > Manoa)[2] Idaho[edit] Moscow (University of Idaho)[2] Pocatello (Idaho
> > State University)[2] Rexburg (BYU-Idaho)[2] Illinois[edit] Carbondale
> > (Southern Illinois University Carbondale)[5] Champaign–Urbana
> > (University of Illinois at Urbana–Champaign)[5] Charleston (Eastern
> > Illinois University)[2] DeKalb (Northern Illinois University)[2]
> > Edwardsville (Southern Illinois University Edwardsville)[2] Evanston
> > (Northwestern University)[2] Lebanon (McKendree University)[2] Macomb
> > (Western Illinois University)[2] Normal (Illinois State University)[2]
> > Peoria (Bradley University) Indiana[edit] Bloomington (Indiana
> > University Bloomington)[5] Crawfordsville (Wabash College) Greencastle
> > (DePauw University)[5] Hanover (Hanover College)[2] Marion (Indiana
> > Wesleyan University)[2] Muncie (Ball State University)[2] Oakland City
> > (Oakland City University)[2] Richmond (Earlham College)[2] South Bend
> > (Notre Dame University[2]) "Terre Haute (Indiana State University,
> > Rose-Hulman Institute of Technology)[2]" Upland (Taylor University)[2]
> > Valparaiso (Valparaiso University) West Lafayette (Purdue
> > University)[2] Iowa[edit] Ames (Iowa State University)[2] Cedar Falls
> > (University of Northern Iowa)[2] "Cedar Rapids, Iowa (Coe College )"
> > Decorah (Luther College)[5] Fayette (Upper Iowa University)[2]
> > Grinnell (Grinnell College)[15] Iowa City (University of Iowa)[15]
> > Lamoni (Graceland University)[2] "Mount Vernon, (Cornell College)"
> > Orange City (Northwestern College)[2] Sioux Center (Dordt College)[2]
> > Storm Lake (Buena Vista University)[2] Waverly (Wartburg College)[2]
> > Kansas[edit] Baldwin City (Baker University)[5] Emporia (Emporia State
> > University)[2] Hays (Fort Hays State University)[2] "Lawrence
> > (University of Kansas, Haskell Indian Nations University)[15]"
> > "Manhattan (Kansas State University, Manhattan Christian College)[15]"
> > Pittsburg (Pittsburg State University)[2] Kentucky[edit] Bowling Green
> > (Western Kentucky University)[2] Columbia (Lindsey Wilson College)[2]
> > Georgetown (Georgetown College) Highland Heights (Northern Kentucky
> > University) "Lexington (University of Kentucky, Transylvania
> > University[5]" Louisville (University of Louisville) Morehead
> > (Morehead State University)[2] Murray (Murray State University)[5]
> > Richmond (Eastern Kentucky University)[2] Williamsburg (University of
> > the Cumberlands)[2] "Wilmore (Asbury University, Asbury Theological
> > Seminary)[2]" Louisiana[edit] "Baton Rouge (Louisiana State
> > University, Southern University)" Grambling (Grambling State
> > University)[5] Hammond (Southeastern Louisiana University)[2]
> > Lafayette (University of Louisiana at Lafayette) Monroe (University of
> > Louisiana at Monroe)[2] Natchitoches (Northwestern State
> > University)[2] Ruston (Louisiana Tech University)[2] Thibodaux
> > (Nicholls State University)[2] Maine[edit] Augusta (University of
> > Maine at Augusta)[2] Bar Harbor (College of the Atlantic) Brunswick
> > (Bowdoin College) Farmington (University of Maine at Farmington)[2]
> > Fort Kent (University of Maine at Fort Kent) Gorham (University of
> > Southern Maine)[2] "Lewiston, Maine (Bates College)" Orono (University
> > of Maine)[2] "Waterville (Thomas College, Colby College)"
> > Maryland[edit] "Annapolis (United States Naval Academy, St. John's
> > College)" Chestertown (Washington College)[2] "College Park
> > (University of Maryland, College Park)[16]" Cumberland (Allegany
> > College of Maryland) Emmitsburg (Mount St. Mary's University)[2]
> > Frostburg (Frostburg State University)[5] Princess Anne (University of
> > Maryland Eastern Shore)[5] "Towson (Towson University, Goucher
> > College)[2]" Salisbury (Salisbury University)[2] Westminster (McDaniel
> > College) Massachusetts[edit] "Boston (Boston University, Boston
> > College, Boston Conservatory, New England Conservatory, Brandeis
> > University, Northeastern University, UMass Boston, Emmanuel College,
> > Bunker Hill Community College, Roxbury Community College, Suffolk
> > University, Simmons College, among many others)" Bridgewater
> > (Bridgewater State College)[2] "Cambridge (Harvard University,
> > Massachusetts Institute of Technology)(Lesley University, Cambridge
> > College, Longy School of Music)[15]" Chestnut Hill (Boston College)
> > The Colleges of Worcester Consortium: Dudley (Nichols College) North
> > Grafton (Cummings School of Veterinary Medicine at Tufts University)
> > Paxton (Anna Maria College) "Worcester (Assumption, Becker, Clark
> > University, Holy Cross, Mass. College of Pharmacy & Health Sciences,
> > Quinsigamond Community College, UMass Medical School, Worcester State
> > University, Worcester Polytechnic Institute)" The Five College Region
> > of Western Massachusetts: "Amherst (Amherst College, Hampshire
> > College, University of Massachusetts Amherst)[15]" Northampton (Smith
> > College) South Hadley (Mount Holyoke College) Fitchburg (Fitchburg
> > State College) North Adams (Massachusetts College of Liberal Arts)
> > "Springfield (American International College), (Springfield College),
> > and (Western New England College)" "Waltham (Bentley University),
> > (Brandeis University)" Williamstown (Williams College) Framingham
> > (Framingham State University) Michigan[edit] "Adrian (Adrian College,
> > Siena Heights University)" Albion (Albion College)[17] Allendale
> > (Grand Valley State University) Alma (Alma College) Ann Arbor
> > (University of Michigan)[1] Berrien Springs (Andrews University)[2]
> > Big Rapids (Ferris State University)[2] East Lansing (Michigan State
> > University)[2] "Flint (Kettering University, University of
> > Michigan-Flint)" Hillsdale (Hillsdale College) Houghton (Michigan
> > Technological University)[5] "Kalamazoo (Western Michigan University,
> > Kalamazoo College)[2]" Marquette (Northern Michigan University)[2]
> > Midland (Northwood University) Mount Pleasant (Central Michigan
> > University)[2] Olivet (Olivet College)[2] Saginaw (Saginaw Valley
> > State University) Sault Ste. Marie (Lake Superior State University)
> > Spring Arbor (Spring Arbor University)[2] Ypsilanti (Eastern Michigan
> > University)[2] Minnesota[edit] Bemidji (Bemidji State University)[2]
> > Crookston (University of Minnesota Crookston)[2] "Duluth (University
> > of Minnesota Duluth, Lake Superior College, The College of St.
> > Scholastica, University of Wisconsin–Superior, Duluth Business
> > University" "Faribault, South Central College" "Mankato (Minnesota
> > State University, Mankato),[2] Bethany Lutheran College" Marshall
> > (Southwest Minnesota State University)[2] "Moorhead (Minnesota State
> > University, Moorhead, Concordia College)[18]" Morris (University of
> > Minnesota Morris)[2] "Northfield (Carleton College, St. Olaf
> > College)[5]" "North Mankato, South Central College" "St. Cloud (St.
> > Cloud State University, The College of St. Scholastica)[2]" St. Joseph
> > (College of Saint Benedict)[2] St. Peter (Gustavus Adolphus
> > College)[2] "Winona (Winona State University, St. Mary's University of
> > Minnesota)[19]" Mississippi[edit] Cleveland (Delta State
> > University)[2] Hattiesburg (University of Southern Mississippi)[20]
> > Itta Bena (Mississippi Valley State University)[2] Oxford (University
> > of Mississippi)[2] Starkville (Mississippi State University)[2]
> > Missouri[edit] Bolivar (Southwest Baptist University)[2] Cape
> > Girardeau (Southeast Missouri State University)[2] "Columbia
> > (University of Missouri, Stephens College, Columbia College)[20]"
> > Fayette (Central Methodist University)[2] Fulton (Westminster College
> > and William Woods University).
> ```

Comment: Its helpful if you provide the full error message

Comment: you do not declare a `State` in the second if clause

Comment: Please edit your question to also include a sample of your file as **text**, not as an image.

Comment: Follow the instructions from the linked question and then do `set(df.State)`

Comment: I am interested in a solution via the Py dict and then building a dataframe based on that.  So my question pertains how to do this approach.